# How to check if file copy and writing was successful

Tags: c++, c++11, ifstream, ofstream

I am using C++ 11 to copy a file this way:

```
std::ifstream  src(srcPath, std::ios::binary);
std::ofstream  dst(destinationPath, std::ios::binary);
dst << src.rdbuf();
```

I am creating a new file this way:

```
std::ofstream out(path);
out << fileContent;
out.close();
```

In both cases, how do I check if the operation actually succeeded or if it failed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`operator bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) is defined for the `ostream&` return of the stream insertion. So you can test for success with an `if` statement:

```
if (dst << src.rdbuf())
    { // ... }

if (out << fileContent)
    { // ... }
```